# $wpdb insert array

Tags: wpdb

I need to insert multiple array. I get error: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

My example code:

```
 $array_info is 
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => d
        [1] => e
        [2] => f
    )

)

 $data = array(
        'blog_id' => NULL,
        'post_id' => $id,
        'ing' => $array_info
        );
        $insert = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);
```

Comment: What is your `$table_name` value?

Comment: This value is correct wp_tablename

Comment: Per the [Codex page on WPDB](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows), `$wpdb->insert()` expects `$data` to be an array of column => value pairs.  Your `$data` array doesn't meet that criterion.

Comment: You provided no context to your question, it's not clear why you are doing this, or what the purpose is, as such it is very hard to determine what a correct answer would actually be. Also we do not see the code that generates array_info

Comment: Also, array_info is an array, not a string, as the error says

Comment: I used function serialize(), and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

What is your table structure. Please be aware that a $wpdb->insert call translate the array to an sql statement of the form

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Since there is no such thing as an array type for colums in sql, you will need to either serialize any subarray or make a seperate field for each item in the sub array (and move items from the subarray to the main array).

Please be aware that it is generally not a good practice to have structured data inside a SQL field.